# Converting coordinates point to coordinates lines - and retaining variables

Tags: r, line, geospatial, points

I have a large dataset with the x,y coordinates of 91 different trajectories distinguished by the variable `ID`:

```
>     head(trjct)
     t        x      y        z     Etot   ID
1 0.00 696621.4 167730 1680.960 1192.526 sim1
2 0.01 696621.4 167730 1680.959 1192.526 sim1
3 0.02 696621.4 167730 1680.958 1192.526 sim1
4 0.04 696621.4 167730 1680.952 1192.526 sim1
5 0.06 696621.4 167730 1680.942 1192.526 sim1
6 0.08 696621.4 167730 1680.929 1192.526 sim1
```

I have managed to convert these coordinates into lines:

```
  coordinates(trjct) <- ~x+y
  trjct_lines_coords <- lapply(split(trjct, trjct$ID), function(x) Lines(list(Line(coordinates(x))), x$ID[1L])) #first column = row number
```

However the information contained within the variable `Etot` is not included. How can I create a list of lines, each with one line and corresponding `Etot` values in the list?

I want to create a data.frame for the lines, grouped by id (one row for each line) and I also want to keep the information contained in `Etot`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it with the `sf` package, which is good at dealing with geometrical and spatial data. Note that you need the development version of `ggplot2` to use `geom_sf` for the plot. The approach is pretty simple and reflects how cool `sf` can be because it works well with other `tidyverse` tools. We use `st_as_sf` to convert to an `sf` object (put the point coordinates into a geometry column), `group_by(ID)` and `summarise` to collapse the points into a `MULTIPOINT` and `Etot` into one value, and then `st_cast` to convert the `MULTIPOINT` geometries into lines.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.0, proj.4 4.9.3
tbl <- read_table2(
  "t        z     Etot   ID
0.00 1680.960 1192.526 sim1
0.01 1680.959 1192.526 sim1
0.02 1680.958 1192.526 sim1
0.04 1680.952 1192.526 sim1
0.06 1680.942 1192.526 sim1
0.08 1680.929 1192.526 sim1"
)
#> Warning in rbind(names(probs), probs_f): number of columns of result is not
#> a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
#> Warning: 1 parsing failure.
#> row # A tibble: 1 x 5 col     row col   expected actual        file         expected   <int> <chr> <chr>    <chr>         <chr>        actual 1     6 ID    ""       embedded null literal data file # A tibble: 1 x 5

lines <- tbl %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("t", "z")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Etot = mean(Etot)) %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

ggplot(lines) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: i tried to install the development version of ggplot2 as outlined here: https://gist.github.com/kohske/1150934 but i still get the error that **could not find function "ggplot"**

Comment: That gist is 7 years old, `ggplot2` has moved since. Run `install.packages("devtools")`, then, `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`. Then when you run `library(tidyverse)` it should show that you are on `ggplot2` version 2.2.1.9000